# Check Oracle backup is running

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Just wondering how do I check if a backup is running on an Oracle database. I am on version 11.2.0.2

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how you are doing backups. Are you using RMAN? If you are using recovery manager you can use the corresponding database views like `V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS` or `V$RMAN_BACKUP_SUBJOB_DETAILS`